# How to send Request file path in JSON request in Jmeter Test

Tags: java, jmeter

All i am new to Jmeter and i am trying to create a rest api request that i can use to do some load test. I was able to authenticate and proceed to the next step of sending the post request.

Our Request is basically something like this

```
{"id" : 112, "someversion" : "2.0", "policyData" : "C:/TEMP/PGF/someinput.json" }
```

i was able to capture on the server what a sample request looks like. It seems that we are zipping and doing some base64 encoding before we send the request......

[image]

My main Question is how can i zip and  encode this before posting so it can be similar to that format.

I have tried the following in jsr223 preprocessor:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

String bodyString = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
byte [] requestBody = bodyString.getBytes();
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream(requestBody.length);
GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
```

so in here i need to zip this. it seems it zipping and my request is as this:
[image]

I am thinking i just need to encode the policy data only and not the entire request ......

I need to do something like this in java and encrypt that file possibly before I send it in the request.

```
using (var cryptStream = new CryptoStream(streamWriter.BaseStream, new 
ToBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Write, leaveOpen: true))
using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(cryptStream, 
CompressionMode.Compress))
using (var inputFile = new FileStream(requestData.policyData, 
FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
  inputFile.CopyTo(gzipStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to:

1. Extract the path to file from the request body using [JsonSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
2. [GZip](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-compress-a-file-in-gzip-format/) this file content
3. Encode the bytes array to [Base64](https://blog.mrhaki.com/2009/11/groovy-goodness-base64-encoding.html)

Example code:

```
String bodyString = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
File policyData = new File(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(bodyString).policyData)
def fileStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
def gzipStream = new java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream(fileStream)
gzipStream.write(policyData.bytes)
gzipStream.close()
def gzipped = fileStream.toByteArray()
fileStream.close()
log.info(gzipped.encodeBase64().toString())
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: Thank you so much ....i am going to try this method you just provided. I was able to solve this earlier ......see my answer to my question. Thank you Dmitri T!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help... This is how i had initially solve my issue

```
String bodyString = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue();
ByteArrayOutputStream rstBao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
String JsonRequest = FileUtils.readFileToString(new 
File("C:/TEMP/PGF/pgf_svc_input.json"));
GZIPOutputStream zos = new GZIPOutputStream(rstBao);
zos.write(JsonRequest.getBytes());
IOUtils.closeQuietly(zos);
byte[] bytes = rstBao.toByteArray();
//Here is where i am able to encode the bytes to base 64
Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
vars.put("postDataEncoded64",Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes));
log.info("khemlall this is the content"+ Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes));
log.info(vars.get("postDataEncoded64"));
rstBao.close()

In the body of my request i added the variable:

{
 "id":"22351", 
 "pmmVersion":"2.0",
 "policyData" : "${postDataEncoded64}"
 }
```